# C# linked lists, using Exception Handling to check conditions during Node Deletion

Tags: c#, exception, linked-list

I'm implementing linked lists. I'm trying to code different kinds of functionalities I can which may be of use to me. The reason I'm not using the inbuilt List<>() is because of my requirement of my lab work to implement linked lists our selves which we are going to use for any further functionality.

My current functionalities include printing a single node, printing all nodes, adding a node at the end, replacing a node and one I'm currently working on is deleting/removing a node. (Credits to youtuber Jeff Chastine I mostly used what he did in his tutorial)

I was hoping to have other people look at what I'm doing in delete node (in LinkedList.cs) because I feel as though using Exception handling may not be the right path.

Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace LinkedListImplementation
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            LinkedList myList = new LinkedList();
            myList.append(3);
            myList.append(14);
            myList.append(14);
            myList.append(34);
            myList.append(89);
            myList.append(556);
            myList.print();
            myList.deleteNode(1);
            myList.print();
            //myList.replaceData(5, 80);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Node.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace LinkedListImplementation
{
    class Node
    {
        public int data;
        public Node nextNode;

        public Node(int data)
        {
            this.data = data;
            nextNode = null;
        }

        public void singleDisplay(int data)
        {
            if(nextNode != null)
            {
                if (this.data == data)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("My data {0}", data);
                }

                nextNode.singleDisplay(data);
            }
            if (nextNode == null)
            {
                if(this.data != data)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Value not found");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("My data {0}", data);
                }

            }
        }

        public void completeDisplay()
        {
            if(nextNode != null)
            {
                Console.Write(data + " -> ");
                nextNode.completeDisplay();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(data);
            }
        }

        public void addNodeAtEnd(int data)
        {
            if(nextNode == null)
            {
                nextNode = new Node(data);
            }
            else
            {
                nextNode.addNodeAtEnd(data);
            }
        }

        public void replaceNodeData(int data, int repData)
        {
            if(this.data == data)
            {
                this.data = repData;
            }
            else
            {
                if(nextNode == null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Value Not Found");
                }
                else
                {
                    nextNode.replaceNodeData(data, repData);
                }
            }
        }



    }
}
```

LinkedList.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace LinkedListImplementation
{
    class LinkedList
    {
        public Node head;

        public LinkedList()
        {
            head = null;
        }

        public void append(int data)
        {
            if (head == null)
            {
                head = new Node(data);
            }
            else
            {
                head.addNodeAtEnd(data);
            }
        }

        public void print()
        {
            if (head != null)
            {
                head.completeDisplay();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("List Not Found");
            }
        }

        public void singlePrint(int data)
        {
            if(head != null)
            {
                head.singleDisplay(data);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("List Not Found");
            }
        }

        public void replaceData(int data, int repData)
        {
            if(head != null)
            {
                head.replaceNodeData(data, repData);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("List Not Found");
            }

        }

        public void deleteNode(int data)
        {
            Node current = head;
            Node temp = new Node(0);

            if(current == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("List does not exist");
            }
            else
            {
                while (current.data != data)
                {
                    temp = current;
                    current = current.nextNode;
                    try
                    {
                        if (current.data != data && current == null)
                        {}
                    }
                    catch(Exception)
                    {
                        //Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                        break;
                    }

                }
                try
                {
                    if (current.data == data && current.nextNode == null)
                    {
                        current = temp;
                        current.nextNode = null;
                    }
                    else if (current.data == data && current.nextNode != null)
                    {
                        current = current.nextNode;
                        temp.nextNode = current;
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }

            }



        }


    }
}
```

Comment: singly or doubly linked list delete implementation ?

Comment: As it doesn't look like you are asking a question but requesting code review, perhaps this would be a good candidate for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Ah sorry I was unaware about that. I'll make sure to sue that for any future code reviews. Thank you.

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw it is at the moment singly.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using multiple try catch blocks in the deleteNode method, which should be DeleteNode by the way? A single try catch block will give you cleaner code, and catch any exceptions that happen in it. You could always add specialized exception types if you were looking for better error handling. See the multiple catch block example [here](http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-exception-handling)

```
        try
        {
            if (current == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("List does not exist");
            }
            else
            {
                while (current.data != data)
                {
                    temp = current;
                    current = current.nextNode;
                    if (current.data != data && current == null)
                    {
                    }


                }
                if (current.data == data && current.nextNode == null)
                {
                    current = temp;
                    current.nextNode = null;
                }
                else if (current.data == data && current.nextNode != null)
                {
                    current = current.nextNode;
                    temp.nextNode = current;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ah I see, that indeed helps. Thank you. Though I'll be taking my question to code review since i was just apprised that this would be not the correct forum to ask for code reviewing.